# Performing OSM place search with integrated python console in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, openstreetmap

I've been trying to find documentation on how to use the OSM place search plugin with the integrated python console on QGIS and had no success so far.

Does anybody know what are the classes/methods required to perform an OSM place search with a specific address with the integrated Python console in QGIS?

Comment: No, but after reading the plugin description I see it runs Nominatim.  You do not mention your OS but you could install GeoPy to the same Python interpreter that QGIS is using and use GeoPy to get the coordinates and then regular pygqis to zoom to those coordinates. https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and https://landscapearchaeology.org/2018/installing-python-packages-in-qgis-3-for-windows/

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "**perform an OSM place search with a specific address with the integrated Python console in QGIS**"? Do you want to search an address and add the results to the plugin's table OR do you want to search an address and add the first result returned to the map?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz The second part you're mentioning. I wanna perform a search for a specific address and add the resulting layer to the layers in QGIS. All within the integrated python console in QGIS.